# How do I pass a variable from a defined function to a while loop?

Tags: python, n-queens

I am creating a program that solves the n queens problem. The pseudocode we were given is as follows...

```
import random
# ask the user for an N value
# generate a candidate NQ solution [random.randint(0,n-1) for x in range(n)]
# define a function to count number of conflicts()
# while number of conflicts in NQ > 0
    # randomize (or improve) NQ
# print NQ
# print number of iterations
```

So far this is what I have...

```
#ask for n value
n = input("Give me a board dimension: ")
n = int(n)
# generate a candidate NQ solution [random.randint(0,n-1) for x in range(n)]
nq = [random.randint(0,n-1) for x in range(n)]

print(nq)
# define a function to count number of conflicts()
def count_conflicts( nq ):
    for i in range( len(nq)-1):
        for j in range(i+1,len(nq) ):
            if abs(i-j)==abs(nq[i]-nq[j]):
                global conflicts
                conflicts += 1
        return conflicts


#print(conflicts)
x = count_conflicts(nq)
print(x)

# while number of conflicts in NQ > 0
# randomize (or improve) NQ
while (conflicts > 0):
    nq = [random.randint(0,n-1) for x in range(n)]
# print NQ
print(nq)
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/wills/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/lasttry.py", line 25, in <module>
    x = count_conflicts(nq)
  File "C:/Users/wills/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/lasttry.py", line 20, in count_conflicts
    conflicts += 1
NameError: name 'conflicts' is not defined
```

How do I increase conflicts by 1 each time a conflict is found, and how do I use that variable outside of the count_conflicts() function?

Comment: You first need to instantiate `conflicts` before you increment it.  Also, I'm not sure why it needs to be a global.  Just set `conflicts = 0` in the first line of your `count_conflicts` function. Also, I don't see how your final while loop ever terminates.

Comment: i added conflicts = None  above where it asks for the n value, I am still getting the same error?

Comment: Try `None + 1` and you'll see why that doesn't work.

Comment: Disregard, I made a mistake, I placed the conflicts = 0 in count_conflicts() like you said, and now it seems to be functioning properly. So how can I use the number of conflicts in the while loop?

Comment: My idea is this...

count_conflicts()
           conflicts counting...
        returns # of conflicts

While (conflicts > 0)
       Randomize numbers 

else: present solution

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate `conflict`, and then use it in the function.

```
conflicts = 0 # or any other value
def count_conflicts( nq ):
    global conflicts
    for i in range( len(nq)-1):
        for j in range(i+1,len(nq) ):
            if abs(i-j)==abs(nq[i]-nq[j]):
                conflicts += 1
        return conflicts
```

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly what the error says, conflicts is undefined.

Put `conflicts = 0` at the top of your code and reset it to 0 at an appropriate point if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should define conflicts = 0 before the `for i in range( len(nq)-1):` loop. The `+= 1` operator increments by one the value which, in your case, is not previously defined.

Also you have to ident your code properly, because you are returning the value before the first loop ends.